# Passing unique dictionary addresses to class instances

Tags: python, json, oop

Here I am pulling json data from different websites and I intend to embed some of the retrived information into instance variables. The trouble is, the json package retrieved keeps the info I want under different keys and list positions, and so each dictionary address is unique per website.

I am struggling to find a way of creating a new instance of a class and passing different dictionary keys to lookup for when new data is retrived.

Something like this would be too easy I feel...

```
import requests, json

class B(object):

    def __init__(self, name, url, size, price):

        self.name = name
        self.url = url

        self.size_address = size
        self.price_address = price

        self.size = 0
        self.price = 0

        self.data = {}

    def retrieve(self):
        #Data grab from web
        try:
            grab = requests.get(self.url, timeout=10)
            self.data = tick.json()
        except:
            raise RuntimeError(self.name + 'Error')


    def size(self):
        self.size = data[self.size_address]
        print self.size

    def price(self):
        self.price = data[self.price_address]
        print self.price

>>> a = B('Dave','www.dave.com/api',['names'][0]['size'],[['names'][0]['prices'][0])
>>> a.size()
42030.20
```

I've had a look at abstract methods as well as binding functions written outside of the class definition. Binding functions looked to be promising but I couldn't create the same function for each class with different variables because I would be using the same name.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: While the websites may use different structures, I imagine the structure for all requests made to a specific website would be consistent (otherwise what's the point of the API).  Why not create a dictionary of translation functions (or references to translation functions)?  Key the translations off the domain name.

Comment: Along the lines of what @paidhima suggests — if you had a structure describing where the items of interest were located for each website — you could make `size` and `price` [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) of the class that used the website to look-up were/how to get these items and then do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to address this is through [design-pattern decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) (thanks to [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) for the correction) employing [method injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object).

Suppose you start off with the following class:

```
class Info(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

This class takes a dictionary `data`, and stores it. The problem is, the key might change among instances.

E.g.,

```
a1 = Info({'a': 3, 'b': 4})
a2 = Info({'c': 5, 'b': 4})
```

and we then realize that for `a1`, the key is `a`, but for `a2`, the key is `c`.

So, we can write a function like so:

```
import types

def patch_it(info, key):
    def get_it(info):
        return info.data[key]

    info.get_it = types.MethodType(get_it, info)
```

which takes an `Info` *object* and a key, and injects into it a method `get_it` that returns, when called the dictionary's value of that key.

Here's an example:

```
>> a1 = Info({'a': 3, 'b': 4})
>> patch_it(a1, 'a')
>> a1.get_it()
3

>> a2 = Info({'c': 5, 'b': 4})
>> patch_it(a2, 'c')
>> a2.get_it()
5
```

---

*Note*

For the specific above example, it is an overkill - Why not add a member to info specifying what is the key? The point is that this method allows you to manipulate objects of `Info`, in arbitrarily complex ways, independently from the class itself.

Comment: What role do decorators have in this?

Comment: @martineau The design pattern [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) rather than the Python language feature: "In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern (also known as Wrapper, an alternative naming shared with the Adapter pattern) is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class."

Comment: Yes I had crossed this and thought I had found my solution, but the problem with method injection is that I would like all of the instances to have the method that grabs the size / price out of the dictionary have the same name. So I guess I would need to redefine 'def price' and 'def size' before binding the method.

Could I possible create a script where I redifine the two methods after each binding?

Thanks a lot for your help guys

EDIT: I just realised I need to play with your code a little for it to make sense to me. Let me get back to you :D

Comment: @martineau You're right, I agree. In addition, I neglected to thank you for your justified question which led to the link correction. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I see what you're getting at, but I will need to use a combination of keys, list points to get the exact data I'm looking for. For example I need to retrieve the number 2 from this dict:
a1 = Info({'a':{'b':[1,2,3]},'c':5})

Comment: @Sean Daley it's the same principle, though, no? The decorators could get more complicated, or there could be a cascade of decorators, but, personally, I'd go this way.

Comment: I should just say, thanks a lot for your time Ami, this is really helping a lot. This is working, though what would you recommend be the best way to use an arbitrary amount of values? e.g. sometimes the data is in ['size'] and sometimes it's in ['return'][0]['properties']['size'][2]. Should I just make a bunch of if statements to check how many arguments I have and run the appropriate patch function? Or I could just pass all the key values into an array and pass that in. Would still require a few if-thens though.